# Gnome Shell Panel Shadow covering windows

Tags: css, gnome-shell

I've added a box-shadow to the gnome-shell top panel

```
#panel {
    ...
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The shadow is show but, as you can see from the image below, it covers maximized windows.

[image]

I tried adding a negative z-index attribute to panel style but it still covers the windows. Is there a way to have the windows layer above panel shadow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in contact with GS developers and they clarified that this is a deliberate choice. The top panel is stacked above the windows group and that's why its shadow casts above them. This behavior won't change event in the future.